# Maven Property file plugin replaces whole content of property file while writing

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I am using Maven Property file plugin ( goal write-project-properties ) to write project properties into a Property file of my Java project. However my property file contains some more properties apart from the one that I want to update.

For eg. contents of my prop file are

```
a=123
b=345
c=567
```

I want to update just b and c values using property file plugin. My POM.xml contains

```
<properties>
   <b>789</b>
   <c>890</c> 
</properties>
```

However while running mvn properties:write-project-properties it updates b & c values and removes "a". Is there a way i can retain a and just update b & c values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not the proper plugin to use if you want to replace some values in a file.

You better use the [resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) by placing placeholders in your property file that will be replaced by the corresponding defined properties in your pom file.